# Хранимые процедуры MySQL

Tags: mysql, база-данных, процедуры

Всем привет, есть такое задание:
создать хранимые процедуры на SELECT, INSERT/UPDATE и DELETE. Есть таблица(my_table) для этих процедур с двумя столбцами ID и NAME. 
Не могу понять как например запрос

```
select * from my_table;
```

превратить в хранимую процедуру. В голову пришло только:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sel ()
begin
select * from my_table;
end
//
```

Подскажите пожалуйста что не так, и где про это почитать? Эти процедуры будут мне нужны в серверном приложении (на java), которое будет их вызывать. Нужно в них сразу что то предусмотреть, или они вызываются просто по имени?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Подскажите пожалуйста что не так

Да всё так. Если DELIMITER не забыть. Ну можно разве для синтаксической строгости точку с запятой после END поставить... Плюс ремарка, что для процедуры из одного оператора блок BEGIN-END в общем-то и необязателен...

> где про это почитать?

В документации, вестимо. [Stored Programs and Views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-views.html).

Comment: А как можно сделать в одной процедуре добавление/изменение строки в таблице? По логике она должна сравнивать значение с имеющимися в таблице и добавлять (если нет), редактировать (если да)?

Comment: Для этого не нужна процедура, достаточно уникального индекса и INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (либо REPLACE).